# How to Debug Extended Functions in XSLT Using Saxon?

Tags: java, xslt, xslt-1.0, saxon

I have been reading through programming blogs about how to use Extended Functions with XSLT and Saxon, and can't seem to reference external Java functions in the XSLT successfully.  I am getting the following error whenever I run the transform:

```
Cannot find a matching 0-argument function named {come.acme.javaxslt.business.CarBusiness}getModel()
  at xsl:apply-templates (file:/C:/Users/Dave/workspace/acme-javaXSLT-demo/cars.xsl#18)
     processing /cars/car[1]/model[1]
  in built-in template rule
  at xsl:apply-templates (file:/C:/Users/Dave/workspace/acme-javaXSLT-demo/cars.xsl#10)
     processing /cars
EXCEPTION: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Cannot find a matching 0-argument function named {com.acme.javaxslt.business.CarBusiness}getModel()
; SystemID: file:/C:/Users/Dave/workspace/acme-javaXSLT-demo/cars.xsl; Line#: 30; Column#: -1
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Cannot find a matching 0-argument function named {com.acme.javaxslt.business.CarBusiness}getModel()
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.ErrorExpression.evaluateItem(ErrorExpression.java:58)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.ErrorExpression.iterate(ErrorExpression.java:71)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.Atomizer.iterate(Atomizer.java:180)
...
```

**Referenced Java Class:**

```
package com.acme.javaxslt.business;

public class CarBusiness {

    public static String getModel(){
        return "/";
    }
}
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:cars="com.acme.javaxslt.business.CarBusiness">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My Car Collection</h2>  
  <xsl:apply-templates/>  
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="car">
  <p>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="make"/>  
    <xsl:apply-templates select="model"/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="make">
  Make: <span style="color:#ff0000">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
  <br />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="model">
  Artist: <span style="color:#00ff00">
  <xsl:value-of select="cars:getModel()"/></span>
  <br />
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Use of Saxon in Java:**

```
TransformerFactory tfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tfactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File(xslID)));
transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new File(sourceID)), new StreamResult(new File("html/report.html")));
```

As soon as the above is run, the errors occur.

Even if I substitute my custom Java class for an inbuilt java method in the XSLT, I get the same error.  So it's obvious that the XSLT is not hooking up with Java.

The recommended approach is to add -TJ to the JVM options, or do something with FeatureKeys.TRACE_EXTERNAL_FUNCTIONS, but I've searched high and low on the web to find out more information on how to do this so that I can see why my XSLT is not hooking up with external Java functions, to no avail.

Please, can someone help me figure out what my problem is?

This is happening for Saxon PE and HE, I haven't tried other versions yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have used an earlier version of Saxon, Saxon-B 9.1.0.8, as pointed out here:

http://sourceforge.net/p/saxon/discussion/94027/thread/33492ab5/

As soon as I put the older jar files in the path, then the above XSLT called the java function correctly.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. It should also work with Saxon-PE. If you need help with Saxon-specific questions, please ask on http://saxonica.plan.io/ - it's hit and miss whether we spot a question on StackOverflow.

Comment: Ah yes thanks Michael, I had two versions of my project and confused myself.  It does indeed work with Saxon-PE.